# What type of receptacle has three arc-shaped slots, one with an L?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, cord-and-plug

Found in a parking garage at work, but I'm not 100% sure what NEMA type it is. It's on a 30 amp two-pole breaker in a panel with 3-phase power to it.

The outlet reads 30A, 250V.

[image]

Comment: From the photo, look *similar to* https://www.amazon.com/Marinco-Power-Products-CS8369-Receptacle/dp/B07CX26PSG, but notice center pin in ref.  There are similar lower- power L5-30 receptacles. Best ask at the garage!

Comment: Agreed. To some extent, it looks like an L5-30R or more likely L6-30R (b/c it says 250V), but the notch in the one slot is on the wrong side. Looking at more charts, it maybe looks like  a L10-30R or L11-30R, although no idea what those are used for

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a commercial installation, not at all residential or related to _Home_ Improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Tl;dr: This is probably wired strangely. Don't use it.

That looks like an L11-30R. Picture at the bottom of this answer. The blade key configuration is wrong for an L6-30R, which has a key that turns outward rather than inward.

That makes this a three-phase ungrounded outlet. It would normally be connected to all three phases with no neutral and no ground. Since you know it's connected to two phases instead, it can't be wired normally.

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that your goal is to set up EV charging. I wouldn't trust this outlet for that. If it is wired correctly it is lacking the ground that you need. If it's wired unusually it may have the needed ground, but it may well also have shortcuts elsewhere in the wiring which would create an issue for your charging.

[image: Leviton 2670 30-Amp, 250-Volt- 3PY, Flush Mounting Locking Receptacle, Industrial Grade, Non-Grounding, V-0-MAX, Black]

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say it's wired as if it were an **L10-30R** which would be labeled 125/250V.  The dimensional specifications for all NEMA receptacle types, [NEMA WD 6](https://www.nema.org/standards/view/wiring-devices-dimensional-specifications), is available free from NEMA.

Comment: @Theodore it's like you're reading my mind, I edited the L10-30R in to and out of the answer a couple of times as I debated going there. Ultimately I think it someone wired an L11-30R as if it were a L10-30R I wouldn't trust anything about this setup. It could have a neutral instead of an EGC for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is a hubbell type 50 amp receptacle,hot, hot, ground, so about a nema 6-50, but will not match. According to this site.  https://www.hubbell.com/wiringdevice-kellems/en/Products/Electrical-Electronic/Wiring-Devices/Locking-Devices/50A-Twist-Lock/c/2027737

Will need a Hubbell plug to use it, if it is still powered/working.

EDIT   The questioner has pointed out it is a 30 amp receptacle.  This is the proper link.  https://www.hubbell.com/hubbell/en/Products/Electrical-Electronic/Wiring-Devices/Locking-Devices/Insulgrip-Twist-Lock/Locking-Devices-Twist-Lock-Industrial-Flush-Receptacle-30A-250V-2-Pole-3-Wire-Grounding-L6-30R-Screw-Terminal-Black/p/1638563  A NEMA L6-30 plug might fit in it.

Comment: Note that as it says, this is a "twist lock" connection; the pug is inserted, then turned clockwise to lock it in place so it won't pull out accidentally. I've mostly seen these in exhibit halls, hotels, and theaters where the distribution of power may change from week to week and a solid-but-frequently-reconfigurable connection is needed.

Comment: @keshlam  Do you know if hubell is more antique or industrial use?  I think nema has most of the household use.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot how much it looks like it says 50A on the front. It actually says 30A.

Comment: The photo very clearly shows 50. If one is "30 in real life" it's not the one in the photo.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I agree that the photo shows 50, but have also seen photos on here where they change just by looking at them.  I think what OP says from seeing the actual receptacle carries more weight than what a photo shows.   Hubbell's own photos show the difference, since 50 amp has a centre post.

Comment: See the updated picture in different light showing it saying 30a.

Comment: Rather than appending corrections, just refactor the answer to be correct top to bottom. There's no need to preserve the post history here. That's all in the edit log.

Answer (score 1):

It almost looks like it has 50A stamped on it, but I don't believe there ever was such thing as a NEMA L6-50 connector.  Looks a lot like a NEMA L6-30R, and based on the breaker that would support that.

I've used them primarily for UPS and PDU in datacenters and offices.  In a parking garage, it might be there for a big piece of cleaning/maintenance equipment.

There is also a [CS8265](https://www.elliottelectric.com/P/Item/HWD/CS8265C/) (california standard, but common for power distribution at concerts, festivals, etc) that looks VERY similar and is also rated 250V/50A.

[image]